# Australian PR - Skills assesment - Web developer vs Software Engineer

Tags: visa, australia, pr

I am an Indian citizen, applying for an EOI for Australian PR (skilled independent visa subclass 189). I have the required points and am halfway through the form. I have a question regarding the skill to select.

I work on Web Applications, primarily. It includes requirement gathering, development, deployment, testing, support etc. But my experience letters have it mentioned as 'Web Developer' for the first 2 employers, 'Senior Software Engineer' for one and 'Team Lead UI' for the current. Which skill should I select? I have chosen 'Software Engineer' for the time being, since what we do falls under that. Will the position mentioned on my experience letters matter?

Comment: You can only call yourself a "Software engineer" in immigration proceedings if you have a matching degree.

Comment: I have Bachelors and Masters degrees in Computer Science. Do they match?

Comment: Yes. "Most occupations in this unit group have a level of skill commensurate with a bachelor degree or higher qualification. At least five years of relevant experience and/or relevant vendor certification may substitute for the formal qualification. In some instances relevant experience and/or on-the-job training may be required in addition to the formal qualification (ANZSCO Skill Level 1)." http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/Product+Lookup/1220.0~2013,+Version+1.2~Chapter~UNIT+GROUP+2613+Software+and+Applications+Programmers

Comment: Thanks for the link! Yes I do have the relevant experience. What about the assessment authority (or similar) field? All of them seem Australian to me. Will my experience letters count?

Comment: All assessment authorities are Australian, as this involves determining the Australian equivalent of your overseas qualifications and experience.  In your case, I think the relevant authority is the [Australian Computer Society](https://www.acs.org.au/msa/information-for-applicants.html).  You should visit their web site for further information on their process.

Comment: I have studied, am working and living in India, does that mean I too have to get the assessment done?

Comment: It's worth noting that, even if you are unable to call yourself a 'software engineer' during immigration proceedings, that 'engineer' is not a protected term in Australia and the majority of 'software engineer' jobs are filled from a variety of different disciplines.

Comment: @MelK. Thanks! I am looking at the assessment portal.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde they will take your application fee, and will tell you to be on your way... let me know when this happens...

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Seriously? How do I get it done properly? Btw I copied your sample experience letter from one of the answers that I found here.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde ACS is not the problem... they throw away some of your experience but it is expected... IMMI are the ones that are not regulated in any way and can't be complained to anyone... They took 7k AUD from me then told me that what ACS gave me in points does not matter and refused to refund me... When I tried to appeal they just said that I can't... Australian immigration is one big scam... So best of luck...

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Also why would you even want to go to kangarooland (I know water going the other way into toilet is exciting still...) they are racist against Indians like hell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violence_against_Indians_in_Australia_controversy I would recommend UK if you are looking to migrate somewhere...Or Canada if you have no work experience as you start from 0 there...